# Chatting with OpenTok iOS

Tags: restkit

I am going to implement by chatting functionality wit open tok, and node.js
I have gone through http://www.tokbox.com/blog/creating-chat-roulette-on-ios-with-node-js-socket-io-and-opentok/

but here I have problem, in this sample Restkit old version has been used.

here goes code
- (void)initHandshake

{

```
[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", serverUrl]];

NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

time = time * 1000;

[[RKClient sharedClient] get:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/socket.io/1?t=%.0f", time] delegate:self];
```

}
how can I generate RKrequest object by using new Restkit SDK 2.0
here we need to use RKObject manager, instead of RKclient

Thanks,
AKhileshwar Babu

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You should either checkout the old version of RestKit, or use AFNetworking (because the code used in the sample doesn't actually use any mapping features from RestKit).